# DataGridView update datasource thwarted by ProcessDataGridViewKey?

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, bindingsource

I have a datagridview as seen below. On the CellEndEdit event, it updates a table in a MySql database - but only if you click on another cell, not when you strike enter, tab, down arrow, etc..

```
DataAdapter da = new DataAdapter();
DataGridView dg = new DataGridView();
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

private void fillDataGrid()
{
     da.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE idBlah = @id;", mySqlCon);
     da.Fill(dt);
     bs.DataSource = dt;
     dg.DataSource = bs;
     MySqlCommandBuilder cmb = new MySqlCOmmandBuilder(da);
}
void da_CellEndEdit(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     da.Update((DataTable)bs.DataSource);
}
```

I overrode the following methods in a custom datagridview class to try and skip whatever is being triggered.

```
 protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            this.EndEdit();
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
    }

    protected override bool ProcessDataGridViewKey(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            this.EndEdit();
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessDataGridViewKey(e);
    }
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I am not sure where to go from here.

EDIT
Actual code:

```
private BindingSource bindingSourceDependents = new BindingSource();
private MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapterDependents = new MySqlDataAdapter();
private DataTable dt_Dependents = new DataTable();
private void FillDataGridDependents()
{
    MySqlCommandBuilder cmb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapterDependents);
    dataAdapterDependents.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Dependents WHERE idGuarentors = " + guarentor.Id + ";", MySqlQueries_Global.MySqlCon());
    dt_Dependents = Guarentor.SelectDependents(guarentor.Id);
    bindingSourceDependents.DataSource = dt_Dependents;
    dataGridViewDependent.DataSource = bindingSourceDependents;
}
private void cellEndEdit(BindingSource bindingSource, DataGridView dg, MySqlDataAdapter da, string columnNameThatNN, int rowIndex, string columnNameForDup, string dupeMessage, Action<string> insertMethod, Action fillMethod)
{

   if (dg.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnNameThatNN].Value != DBNull.Value)
    {
        try
        {

            da.Update((DataTable)bindingSource.DataSource);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (dg.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnNameForDup].Value != DBNull.Value)
        {
            string value = dg.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnNameForDup].Value.ToString();


            bool contains = ((DataTable)bindingSource.DataSource).AsEnumerable()
                           .Any(row => value.ToUpper() == row.Field<String>(columnNameForDup).ToUpper());
            if (!contains)
            {
                insertMethod(value);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(dupeMessage);
                fillMethod();
            }
        }
        else { fillMethod(); }
    }
}
void dataGridViewDependent_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    cellEndEdit(bindingSourceDependents, dataGridViewDependent, dataAdapterDependents, "idDependents", e.RowIndex, "idDependents", "Critical ERROR contact admin!", dependent.blankmethod, FillDataGridDependents);
}
```

SOLUTION:

changed:

```
      da.Update(((DataTable)bindingSource.DataSource));
```

to:

```
bindingSource.ResetBindings(true);
  da.Update(((DataTable)bindingSource.DataSource));
```

Comment: Why are you handling the key events?

Comment: @junaith - It seems as though the key events prevent the dataadapter from updating,  so I was trying to bypass the default key handling and just call the CellEndedit event immediately.

Comment: @Junaith- yes, the enter, tab, arrow keys end edit for me too, but the subsequent dataAdapter.Update() fails to update the database(while ending edit by clicking on another cell allows the update to succeed). I am handeling the keyup event for the delete key - i removed that from my code to no avail.

Comment: Pressing enter, tab, arrow keys ends the edit operation. I tested in a sample app. It works fine. Keep break point in the CellEndEdit event handler and check. You could post your code (if it is more use pastebin.com to share).

Comment: You are correct, the enter, tab, and arrow keys raises the CellEndEdit event. However, it seems to raise the event before the changes in the datagridview are registered in its datasource.

Comment: I solved the problem by adding bindingSource.ResetBindings(true) just before the dataAdapter.Update().

Answer (score 1):

changed:

```
 da.Update(((DataTable)bindingSource.DataSource));
```

to:

```
bindingSource.ResetBindings(true);
da.Update(((DataTable)bindingSource.DataSource));
```

Comment: At last a solution that works for this "bug".
Remark: All pointers to the DataGridView will be invalid after the call to ResetBindings.
Eg: DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
row will be pointing nowhere after the reset, so it needs to be set again.